# Can Emoticons in Google Messenger be Moved or Rearranged

Tags: google, google-messages

There are two emoticons in Messenger that I like to use more than others.  Unfortunately, you have to slide quite a few pages to find them.  They are located right next to each other.

Is there a way to move those emoticons to the first page which would reduce the time in searching for them?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, emojis are added from your keyboard, not Messenger, meaning that it all depends on the keyboard app which you are using.

Secondly, most keyboards do not support rearranging the emoticons. You can check out the *Frequently used* tab, though. Most keyboards have that.